# Where I can find System.out.println output when running Selenium in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testing

Where would I find in Eclipse 4.9.0 a view which displays `System.out.println()` outputs?

I am running tests via `Ant` script from the Eclipse's Window. I can see the console output of the build but no internal messages from the tests.

[image]

Sample code:

```
        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("selenium i testowanie"));
        assertEquals(6, links.size());

        for (WebElement link : links) {
            System.out.println("link: "+link.getAttribute("href"));
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the code where your `System.out.println` is?

Comment: @AndiCover Code attached. I just need to show the Console window which would contain my output, so it's more of the Eclipse question.

Comment: Maybe one of the answers here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051174/running-ant-in-eclipse-sql2java-no-output-to-the-console

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link for more information
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/173521/

Comment: The code doesn't really matter it could be a single class file with just `System.out.println()`. I can't find a pane/window for showing JAVA outputs from running Selenium tests.

Comment: Problem is, Console window is not populated with Java related vars when running an Ant script. I am guessing only running it as JUnit will work?

Comment: Tried `Allocate console (necessary for input)` and Ant Home var setup to same one, still no luck. JRE: jdk-10.0.1